# SATA PCIe Controller Card

Tags: hard-disk, pcie, sata, raid-controller

I’m looking for an affordable SATA PCIe controller card that I can use only PC.

I have 4 x 3TB 3.5” SATA hard drives and want to be able to use them on the new  card.

I have read a review of some cards and they say they only support up to 2TB disks. I’m trying to find out what I need to look for for the card to be able to handle big hard disk sizes.

Any recommendations or advice while searching would be great.

Thanks

Comment: What motherboard do you currently have and are the SATA ports on it all currently in use?

Comment: At the moment I have a dell optiplex 3010 and yes the 4 ports are being used. I plan to build my own tower for NAS and virtualisation and want to use the card I buy in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't heard of size limitations on a SATA card, but [this](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816124064&cm_re=sata_card-_-16-124-064-_-Product) is a pretty affordable ($30) card with 4 ports. You might have been looking at hardware RAID cards which arent needed unless you really want to do RAID 5 or 6. (These might have size limits) If you really need a RAID card look at [this](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA3913US3588).

Comment: Since primitive RAID chips don't cost much more than simple SATA controller chips, it's rare to find controller cards that *don't* claim some sort of RAID support.  The card you linked does support drives up to at least 4 TB, though that information is buried in the fine print of the "overview" section.